# travelocity.com SAML2 error webapp

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have problems with the example here: [Configuring Single Sign-On](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Single+Sign-On)

I followed all the steps described it. Once finished configuring the service provider I go

> http://localhost:8080/travelocity.com

Comes out the same web page illustrated in the documentation. I enter the data for the login and I'm addressed in a new page

> https://localhost:9443/authenticationendpoint/login.do?commonAuthCallerPath=%2Fsamlsso&forceAuth=false&passiveAuth=false&sectoken=YWRtaW46YWRtaW4%3D&tenantDomain=carbon.super&sessionDataKey=5c8a2bfa-2408-4eca-aebe-281c63d26f6a&relyingParty=travelocity.com&type=samlsso&sp=travelocity.com&isSaaSApp=false&authenticators=BasicAuthenticator:LOCAL

and I post the data again to log in first. It directs me to an error page:

"SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On
Error when processing the authentication request!
Please try login again."

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar issue, but now it is sorted. Can you please specify the error message on the terminal?

Since you are running the "Identity Server" on the terminal, and has followed the instructions given in the documentation, i presume that you have got the following issue on the terminal (command prompt)

> WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor} -  Signature validation for Authentication Request failed.

The identity server does a signature validation,to avoid man in the middle attacks. Therefore the proper certificate alias should be selected. The proper certificate that should be used is as shown below

[image]

Keep the **"Certificate Alias" as "wso2carbon"**

then the signature verification happens smoothly